# JQuery On Click Outside Of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Live Demo On JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n39nztob/)

I know there are extensive questions on here regarding click outside of an element however I cannot resolve my problem.

My menus second tier you can right-click and currently rename the list item. You can do this only by enter;

```
$("body").on("keydown", "li.Clicked>input", function (e) {
    var inputValue = $(this).val(); 
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked a').show();
        $("ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked a").text(inputValue);
        $("ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked input").remove();
        $("ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked").removeClass('Clicked');
    }
});
```

However I am trying to add an outside click event out of the entire menu area so that the above result also occurs or resets, either way, however I cannot set up anything without it seeming to break.

**Please Note:** Whilst this question has no answer, to see the menu in its fully working form, you must hit the enter key upon choosing to rename otherwise the `.Clicked` class will not be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out...

You can add a focusout listener for the input-element. To make it work in your usecase, you have to put the listener attachement after your input-element was added to the DOM. The focusout listener fires when you click somewhere else or tab out of the input field.

```
$('#MailMenuSecondTier li').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('Rename')) {
        $('ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked a').hide();
        $('ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked').append("<input type='text' value='" + $("ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked a").text() + "'>");
        $('ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked > input').select();

        $('ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked > input').focusout(function(){

          var inputValue = $(this).val(); 
          $('ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked a').show();
          $("ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked a").text(inputValue);
          $(this).remove();
          $("ul.inbox-nav > li > ul > li.Clicked").removeClass('Clicked');
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works, however I do not understand why the `.focusout()` is within the `.click()`. I've not seen this before, could you explain?

Comment: Since you are adding the input dynamically.. so he is binding events to it after its added.. else you can make use of event delegation too..

Comment: @Reddy answered well, be sure your listeners are attached to your elements in DOM if your want to see them acting